# No apparent relation between two time series data

Tags: time-series, self-study, correlation, cross-correlation, covid-19

I have two time series data and I want to understand relationship between them for my a data science project that I am currently working on. The time series plots are given below :
[image]

[image]

The plot of 1-differenced "daily-frequency" data looks like:

[image]

The scatterplot of the two variables(in log-scale) looks like this -

[image]  indicating, there is no correlation between the two variables.

I even built a cross-correlation plot which looks like -

[image] which has the value ~0.4 at lag 0!

I don't know how to analyze the data further to dig out possible relationships between the variables. I wish to build more features using "daily frequency" data with "Confirmed" being  the response variable, but the graphs don't show any relationship between the two variables. Is there any transformation that can help visualize the relationship better ?

Comment: Your second time series looks like something accumulated over time (covid cases?), and the first looks like daily cases. I am jus guessing, but what do they mean? What kind of relationship do you expect? You can do pearson's correlation only if your variables are normally distributed. The second is surely not, the first may be after you remove some outliers. There is a lot to dig out there. I would start doing some histograms, describing how your data varies individually, and think a bit about what they mean.

Comment: The "daily_frequency" is count of frequently used covid related keywords in tweets from jan- May. "Confirmed" is like you said global covid cases. The aim is to see if tweets could be used as a predictor for covid cases